# I configure Route All Network Traffic Through the Tor Network. How configure bridges?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, tor

I use [this tutorial](https://www.wikihow.com/Route-All-Network-Traffic-Through-the-Tor-Network) to route all network traffic through the tor network.

I follow all steps and configure to automatically start Torctl on startup. But i cant configure bridges to can't see if I'm using Tor.

I guess the best tutorial I find is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183145/how-can-i-configure-tor-with-bridge-and-privoxy-to-proxy-entire-system). But later i follow the instructions my network no working.

I need reastar my pc and my network back, but my bridges config in /etc/tor/torrc disappear. Does anyone know what to do ?

Comment: Besides following tutorials, which steps, if any,  have you tried to troubleshoot the problem by yourself?

Comment: Of course, I tried some configuration variations. But nothing works.It is worth mentioning that I do not have a deep knowledge in networks. So were simple attempts

Comment: Would you mind including all of the troubleshooting steps by [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1734517/edit) your question? If you don't want to include the work you've already did, others probably are unwilling to help you. Nobody is interested in asking you every single possible step, only to discover that you've already tried half of the things.

Comment: The 1st tutorial tells to retrieve a program from github and to run it and *et voilà!* But it doesn't describe what happens when it's running. So it actually tells nothing on how it's achieved. One would have to check the content on github. For example there are several iptables rules.